# Background Time for Significant Location Change callback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I can't find info on how long are we allowed to run during the locationUpdate callback when running in the background. Does anyone know?

I also checked [[UIAPplication sharedApplciation] backgroundTimeRemaining] which does not return valid data in this case. I believe it was returning MAX INT or something like that.

Thanks,
Vance

Comment: what do you mean? you can run location in the background as long as you want...

Comment: So basically you get notified when the location changes, so how much work can you do from that notification before the app gets suspended again. For example, there might be 2 hours between notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small test. Looks like after 10 seconds the runloop is paused. So you have only 10 seconds to do work within the location update callback.

Answer (score 1):

You get a short amount of time but you can extend it by starting a background task.  Look for the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandle method on UIApplication.  Using that will give you 10 minutes to finish your task.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what level of accuracy you are setting it up for. The location API is asynchronous, so you can get call backs at any time, depends on the level of uncertainty error that you are asking for. The  more accuracy you are setting it to be, the more callbacks you will get. Obviously it also depends on your movements.